# Addition in Recursion Function

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, if-statement, recursion

My code is to +1 to score when the number in the array is 1 and -1 when the number in the array is -1. But when I run the program it only returns 0. The recursion itself doesn't have an infinite loop, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/* When the tile is -1, score--. When the tile is 1, score++. You cannot go outside the array nor can you go backwards */

/* + 2 through the array */
int jumping( int track[], int size, int location ){
static int score = 0;

if ( track[ location ] == 1 ){
    score++;
}
else if ( track[ location ] == -1 ){
    score--;
}

if (( location == size - 1 ) || ( track[ location + 1 ] == 0 )){
    return score;
}
else{
    jumping( track, size, location + 2 );
}
}

/* Run through the array by 1 */
int stepping( int track[], int size, int location ){
static int score = 0;

if ( track[ location ] == 1 ){
    score++;
}
else if ( track[ location ] == -1 ){
    score--;
}

if ( location == size - 1 ){
    return score;
}
else{
    stepping( track, size, location++ );
}
}

/* Is to calculate the maxium possible score for any given track, with any arrangement using recursion. */
int maxScore( int track[], int size, int location ){
int score = 0; //Keep track of score
int step = stepping( track, size, location );//score by stepping
int jump = jumping( track, size, location );//score by jumping

/* If step is higher or jump and replace according to the highest */
if ( step > jump ){
    score = step;
    return score;
}
else if ( jump > step ){
    score = jump;
    return score;
}
else if ( jump == step ){
    return score;
}
}

int main(){

int simple[2] = { 0, 0 };
int easy[8] = { 0, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0 };
int medium[25] = { 0, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0 };
int mediumhard[3] = { 0, 1, 0 };
int impossible[20] = { 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1,     1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0 };
int insane[40] = { 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1,
                  1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0 };

cout << "1. SIMPLE............................................... " << maxScore( simple, 2, 0 ) << endl;
cout << "2. EASY................................................. " << maxScore( easy, 8, 0 ) << endl;
cout << "3. MEDIUM............................................... " << maxScore( medium, 25, 0 ) << endl;
cout << "4. MEDIUM HARD.......................................... " << maxScore( mediumhard, 3, 0 ) << endl;
cout << "5. IMPOSSIBLE........................................... " << maxScore( impossible, 20, 0 ) << endl;
cout << "6. INSANE............................................... " << maxScore( insane, 40, 0 ) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have an assignment in a condition (`if (( location = size - 1 )...`). Is this intended?

Comment: also, you probably want `return stepping(track,size,location++)` or else there would be no explicit return value

Comment: Note: assignment is in a second if statement as well in `stepping()`.  `if ( location = size - 1 ){`

Comment: @Christian This is suppose to stop the function when it has reached the end of the array instead of using if ( location < size ) but I could try it that way.

Comment: @RNar Alright I'll add that and see it works.

Comment: Ah I might have mistyped that was suppose to be location == size - 1. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 3 problems:

1. in jumping, your exit condition should be `location >= size -2` instead of `location == size-1` since your jumping step is 2
2. in Both jumping and stepping, you should put a return in your recursive call like `return jumping(track, size, location + 2);`
3. in the stepping recursive call, it should be `stepping( track, size, ++location );` instead of `stepping( track, size, location++ );`

Ideone: http://ideone.com/M0C68r

Answer (score 0):

```
/* + 2 through the array */
int jumping( int track[], int size, int location ){
static int score = 0;

if ( track[ location ] == 1 ){
    score++;
}
else if ( track[ location ] == -1 ){
    score--;
}

/*** Need to assign recursion to score; also else condition has no return; suggest replacing with the following ***
if (( location == size - 1 ) || ( track[ location + 1 ] == 0 )){
    return score;
}
else{
    jumping( track, size, location + 2 );
}*/
/*** Also, you need to use size - 2 to prevent overrun ***/
if (( location < size - 2 ) && ( track[ location + 1 ] != 0 ))
    score += jumping( track, size, location + 2 );
return score;
}

/* Run through the array by 1 */
int stepping( int track[], int size, int location ){
static int score = 0;

if ( track[ location ] == 1 ){
    score++;
}
else if ( track[ location ] == -1 ){
    score--;
}

/*** Need to assign recursion to score; also else condition has no return; suggest replacing with the following ***
if ( location == size - 1 ){
    return score;
}
else{
    stepping( track, size, location++ );
}*/
if (location < size - 1)
    score += stepping( track, size, location++ );
return score;
}

/* Is to calculate the maxium possible score for any given track, with any arrangement using recursion. */
int maxScore( int track[], int size, , int location ){
int score = 0; //Keep track of score
int step = stepping( track, size, location );//score by stepping
int jump = jumping( track, size, location );//score by jumping

/* If step is higher or jump and replace according to the highest */
if ( step > jump ){
    score = step;
    //*** See Later *** return score;
}
else if ( jump > step ){
    score = jump;
    //*** See Later *** return score;
}
else /*** Don't need the if, as it is the only remaining condition *** if ( jump == step ) */{
    //*** Score is not set here, is this intentional ***
    //*** See Later *** return score;
}
return score;
}
```